# How to Concat Azure DevOps variables to create new variable

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I would like to concat my Azure key vault resource ID from text and other variables like:

`/subscriptions/$(SubscriptionId)/resourceGroups/$(VaultRg)/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/$(keyVaultName)`

And put that into new variable like `kvid`.

However, when I do this I get:

> 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 17', make sure it
>   follows JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)

Should this be possible? Any ideas where I might be doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you provide more info on where you are doing this? Is it in a task or when defining a variable?

Comment: I get that error when I am running a task but the variable is defined within the pipeline variables.

Comment: so if you are using it in the variables, you could always try escaping characters or alternativly you can just build that kvid up in side of your task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just put a placeholder into your ARM template. That's not going to work; there's no hidden mechanism that silently replaces placeholders with variable values in arbitrary files. You have to explicitly take some sort of action (generally with a task from the marketplace) to fill in values.

**However**, the correct way to achieve what you want is to pass those variables as [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-templates-parameters#define-and-use-a-parameter) to your ARM template, and use standard ARM template parameter syntax to reference them.

Ex:
Define a parameter in your ARM template:

```
"parameters": {
  "keyVaultName": {
    "type": "string",
    "defaultValue": "DefaultKV"
  }
}
```

Then reference the parameters:

`[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('SubscriptionId'), '/resourceGroups/', parameters('VaultRg'), '/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/', parameters(keyVaultName))]`

Then when you use the [Resource Group Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=vsts) task, override the parameters with your chosen values.

> Override template parameters
>   (Optional) To view the template parameters in a grid, click on “…” next to Override Parameters textbox. This feature requires that CORS rules are enabled at the source. If templates are in Azure storage blob, refer to this to enable CORS. Or type the template parameters to override in the textbox. Example, 
>   –storageName fabrikam –adminUsername $(vmusername) -adminPassword $(password) –azureKeyVaultName $(fabrikamFibre).
>
> If the parameter value you're using has multiple words, enclose them in quotes, even if you're passing them using variables. For example, -name "parameter value" -name2 "$(var)"
>   To override object type parameters use stringified JSON objects. For example, -options ["option1"] -map {"key1": "value1" }.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by putting a placeholder. I have another keyvaultid in the parameters list which I want to override in certain situations. It works well if I hard code the complete variable but it does not work too well when I try to concat it.